# Installing Spring ToolSuite in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am starting to develop WebApp using `Spring` Framework. For that I know I have to use `Spring Tool Suite`. I went to the `Eclipse` site for downloads but I am having trouble knowing wich of the four types of downloads suggested in the page below should I choose, sicnce none of them seem to have Spring in its features ?

http://spring.io/tools/eclipse

Any help ?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite just helps you to work with different spring projects. You still have to configure all your dependencies using build tools like maven. If you realy want to work with STS and develop web application when EE version should fit your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for your consideration I wrote the following tutorials about STS

1. Installing Spring Tool Suite
2. Configuring Apache Maven
3. Getting Started: IDE & Projects
4. Configuring The Java Working Set
5. Structuring The Workspace

Complete and more detailed tutorials, available here: [Spring Tutorial](http://manueljordanelera.blogspot.pe/2014/06/springroadmap.html)

Comment: Thanks Manual Jordan. So if I understood well, I will have to follow these tutorials one by oen in order to start developping Spring projects ?

Comment: @akari, not necessarily, but should read all, some of them help you to have a good configuration and environment for developing. BTW my name is Manuel, not Manual =)

Comment: Could you sum up the answer here, too, please? Links to other sites tend to rot over time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using Java EE which btw stands for Enterprise Edition,
I'd recommend just going with

Eclipse Luna -> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Answer (score 1):

Spring Tool Suite is a different download. It can be found here: http://spring.io/tools/sts .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the full distribution downloads on http://spring.io/tools/sts (they are ready-to-use Eclipse distributions with pre-installed Spring tooling) you can also use an Eclipse installation and go to the Eclipse Marketplace to install the Spring tooling into your Eclipse instance.